# View says Users is nil, but psql shows I have users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I am trying to display all the users in a view.  I am using Rails 4.1.0 on Ruby 2.1.1.  I am also using Heroku.

When I run psql command 'select * from users' it shows 3 users.  However, in the view it seems to think my @users variable is nil

This is what my view/controller/model look like:

**view:** (app/views/status/index.html.erb)

```
<% if current_user %>
  <h1>All users</h1>
  <% if @users.nil? %>
    users is nil
  <% else %>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <%= user %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  4
<% else %>
  <%= render 'welcome' %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller:**  (app/controllers/users_controller.rb)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

**Model:**  (app/models/user.rb)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def from_omniauth(auth)
      provider = auth.provider
      uid = auth.uid
      info = auth.info.symbolize_keys!
      user = User.find_or_initialize_by(uid: uid, provider: provider)
      user.name = info.name
      user.avatar_url = info.image
      user.profile_url = info.urls.send(provider.capitalize.to_sym)
      user.save!
      user
    end
  end
  has_many :comments, dependent: :delete_all
end
```

Any help or or thoughts on what I am doing wrong would be great.

Comment: are you getting an error? or nothing shows?

Comment: you check if you are using the same database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For displaying list of `User` objects set in `UsersController`, the index view should be in the file named `app/views/users/index.html.erb`.

Not `app/views/status/index.html.erb` as you are using.

`app/views/status/index.html.erb` is not connected to the `UsersController`; so `@users` is nil there, and it is correctly showing the `users is nil` message.

Comment: If I want to show it on another page how would I do that?

Comment: Set the `@users` value in the appropriate controller.

Comment: or tell the controller to render that template. By default, it will render app/views/users/index.html.erb. You can tell it to `render 'status/index'` instead.